# Cocoapods: Podspec validation, missing header file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

Here is my `podspec`:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "appName"
  spec.version      = "0.1"
  spec.summary      = "Blah blah"
  spec.homepage     = "http://myCompany.com/"
  spec.license      = 'Apache 2.0'
  spec.author       = { "myName" => "me@myCompany.com" }
  spec.source       = { :git => 'ssh://myProjectUrl', :tag => '0.1'}

  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
  spec.source_files = 'source/Classes/**.*'

  spec.frameworks   = ['Foundation', 'UIKit', 'CoreGraphics', 'QuartzCore']

  spec.subspec 'Core' do |cs|
    cs.dependency 'libextobjc', '~> 0.4'
  end

end
```

When I call `pod spec lint`:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
-> myApp (0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  myApp/source/Classes/MyAppDelegate.m:10:9: fatal error: 'MyViewController.h' file not found

Analyzed 1 podspec.
[!] MyApp did not pass validation.
```

The problem is that I totally don't know why it doesn't work. All source codes are inside `/Classes` folder. I have subfolders there (eg. `/Classes/ViewControllers`), maybe the path is wrong..?

Comment: It surely is a problem with recursive search through folders. When I've attached /ViewControllers everything is working ok. Still, it is rather a fix than solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working when I've changed:

```
spec.source_files = 'source/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
```